# How to get a list of values on a XML response?

Tags: c#, xml

I get from a webservice a XML like this:

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <Get_PersonResponse
            xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <Get_PersonResult
                xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/example"
                xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:LASTNAME>DOE</a:LASTNAME>
                <a:EMAIL/>
                <a:FIRSTNAME>JONH</a:FIRSTNAME>
                <a:NUM_CARD/>
                <a:ID_PERSON>12345456</a:ID_PERSON>
                <a:PHONE/>
            </Get_PersonResult>
            <RESP_COMMENT>"Person found"</RESP_COMMENT>
        </Get_PersonResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I want to check if RESP_COMMENT is empty. Then if is not empty get all the values (a:FIRSTNAME, a:LASTNAME, etc)

I got the a:FIRSTNAME on the fiddle but I am not sure if I have to do a bucle for every single value or is a better way to do it:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/cOsX6s

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(output);
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("a:FIRSTNAME");
string lastname = string.Empty;
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    firstname = node.InnerText;
    Console.Write(firstname);
}
```

Comment: Look into xml deserialization. For instance with the [DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=net-5.0) or the [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try xml serialization :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication177
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }

    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Get_PersonResponse", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public Get_PersonResponse Get_PersonResponse { get; set; }

    }
    public class Get_PersonResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public string RESP_COMMENT { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Get_PersonResult", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        public Get_PersonResult  Get_PersonResult { get; set; }
    }
    public class Get_PersonResult
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/example")]
        public string LASTNAME { get;set;}
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/example")]
        public string EMAIL { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/example")]
        public string FIRSTNAME { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/example")]
        public string NUM_CARD { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/example")]
        public string ID_PERSON { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/example")]
        public string PHONE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I print FIRSTNAME ?

Comment: envelope.Body.Get_PersonResponse.Get_PersonResult.FIRSTNAME;

Answer (score 0):

There should be a way to get this values using **xpath**. I have tried a few different things and it seems that the empty prefix on namespace **xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"** is causing problems, see the element **Get_PersonResponse** namespace attribute.

```
<Get_PersonResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

To overcome this problem we need to remove the namespace that is causing the problem before loading the xml.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string output = @"<s:Envelope
            xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
            <s:Body>
                <Get_PersonResponse
                    xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
                    <Get_PersonResult
                        xmlns:a=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/example""
                        xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
                        <a:LASTNAME>DOE</a:LASTNAME>
                        <a:EMAIL/>
                        <a:FIRSTNAME>JONH</a:FIRSTNAME>
                        <a:NUM_CARD/>
                        <a:ID_PERSON>12345456</a:ID_PERSON>
                        <a:PHONE/>
                    </Get_PersonResult>
                    <RESP_COMMENT>""Person found!""</RESP_COMMENT>
                </Get_PersonResponse>
            </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>";

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.LoadXml(output.Replace(@"xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/""", ""));
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/example");

        var personResultNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//s:Envelope/s:Body/Get_PersonResponse/Get_PersonResult", nsmgr);

        foreach (var nodes in personResultNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            var personAttribute = (XmlNode)nodes;
            Console.WriteLine($"{personAttribute.LocalName}:  {personAttribute.InnerText}");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

BTW: I have also tried to add an empty prefix for namespace **xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"** to the **XmlNamespaceManager** but that didn't help.